# Ignore Android soft keyboard for layout purposes

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

When the soft keyboard is displayed, it changes the height parameter of my view. I would like it to ignore that the keyboard is even shown and never resize my layout and simply display the keyboard on top of my activity "as is". Is there a flag I can place in the manifest to ignore the soft keyboard for layout purposes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to change is in [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode)

By Adding android:windowSoftInputMode="" to a given activity you can change the behavior of the activity when calling the sofware keyboard.

[Article on updating Applications for On-screen Input Methods](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)

Also [Android Soft Keyboard Resizes Web View](http://solutions.michaelbrooks.ca/2011/07/05/android-soft-keyboard-resizes-web-view/) is another example solution as well.

Comment: My problem was actually with a WebView, so that was spot on. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

put this in manifest file

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

For more info look at [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Answer (score 0):

I Think your layout has been called from any of the activity so in that activity you can call below code to hide the keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager InputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            InputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(your widget object.getWindowToken(), 0);
```